# Asp.net ready modules

Tags: asp.net

I need to add the ability to register users in my web site.
I'm sure that 1000's of programmers already did this, so why should I build from scratch?
Does someone knows where can I find a module like this as well as other modules?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mind using standard ASP.Net login controls?

Comment: Is it simple? will it include registration form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.Net bulit-in membership has everything you need. Database schema, control as well as APIs.
Check these:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/18/427754.aspx

[4GuysFromRolla Tutorials](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)

[Security Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/security)

Answer (score 0):

A good start is one of ASP.NET tutorials, available here: [How to: Create an ASP.NET Login Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178331.aspx)